# User input to determine the displayed results

Tags: javascript, retool

In Retool I am trying to have the input of one box determine the dispalyed options of a second input box, i.e if you select district one in the "district" box (Districtbox) then it will only display projects A, B and C as selectable options in the "project" box. This is my JS code but the `resultingProject` returns an empty output even if `const inputDistrict = 'One'` or `const inputDistrict = Districtbox.value`

```
  // Given project and district pairs
const projectDistrictPairs = [
  { project: 'A', district: 'One' },
  { project: 'B', district: 'One' },
  { project: 'C', district: 'One' },
  { project: 'D', district: 'Two' },
  { project: 'E', district: 'Three' },
  { project: 'F', district: 'Four' }
];

// Assuming you have an input variable named 'inputDistrict' that holds the input district value
const inputDistrict = 'One';

// Find the resulting project for the selected district
const resultingProject = projectDistrictPairs.find(pair => pair.district === inputDistrict)?.project;

console.log(resultingProject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use filter to filter out projects.

`const inputDistrict = 'One';`

`const resultingProject = projectDistrictPairs.filter(pair => pair.district === inputDistrict);`

This will return the array of JSON

`[
  { project: 'A', district: 'One' },
  { project: 'B', district: 'One' },
  { project: 'C', district: 'One' }
]`
```